# Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement

Tags: javascript

tengo un formulario y lo estoy validando con js y me sale este error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statemen

y este es el codigo gracias :)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("fo").addEventListener('submit', validarFormulario); 
});

function validarFormulario(evento) {
  evento.preventDefault();
  }
  
  var clave = document.getElementById('pass').value;
  if (clave.length < 6) {
    alert('La clave debe ser mayor que 6 caracteres');
    return clave;
    
    var clave = document.getElementById('pass').value;
  if (clave.length > 35) {
    alert('La clave debe ser menor que 35 caracteres');
    return clave;
  };
```

Comment: Pues la verdad tus llaves están bastante regadas, no se exactamente que quieres hacer pero debes saber algo importante, los `return` solo van dentro de `funciones` y tus returns No están dentro de ninguna función.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas duplicando 2 veces la variable ***VAR*** en el mismo *alcance*, y en el **return** estas tratando de retornar la variable clave, para detener la operación solo ingresa *return*, no necesita devolver parámetros "return clave", porque no los recibe, el if solo esta comparando si es verdadero o falso.

```
let clave = document.getElementById('pass').value;

if(clave.length < 6){
alert('Ingrese más de 6 caracteres');
return;
}else if( clave.length > 35){
alert('No ingrese más de 35 caracteres');
return;
}
```

Ver ejemplo:
[Ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/Jonas_Gr/0qyb5k6e/)

Comment: **LISTO YA LO SOLUCIONE GRACIAS**